# H5BP build script - dependencies

Tags: ant, build-automation, html5boilerplate

I'm an ant novice but my expectation is that the build script in h5bp would use last modified info to ensure that it only generated new files when it needed to.  This does not happen - everything seems to run on every invocation of `ant build` .  Is there a way I can prevent this? Is it a design feature of the h5bp build script?

I've extended `project.xml` to ftp to my server when I need to (and also to copy to my development server) which I find really useful.  However since the images to be copied from the `publish` folder have new dates, even though unchanged, they are all ftp'd up each time which is slow and unnecessary.  FWIW I'm running this on Windows 7 (uploading to a Linux/Apache server).

Looking through the `build.xml` file, I see plenty of `overwrite` settings - most to `"no"` and a few to `"yes"`, so I guess some conscious decisions have been made.  Appreciate understanding why.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks

Abo

PS Apart from this, the build script is just great!

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I can answer some of my own question.

The publish (and intermediate) directories are deleted on each build, so the published image files are always regenerated.

Anyone know if there's a reason that the img directory cannot be left in publish and intermediate?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit your question accordingly? Stackoverflow is a question and answer site and not used like forum, questions must be in the question part. And answers are only used for answers.

Answer (score 0):

IT generates a new build from the source each time you build one. Leaving old images would just result in lot of unnecessary files.

Perhaps you could set a flag when the image files are FTPed for the first time, and then on not upload the images unless specifically asked to do so?